# Is the HttpServletRequest-object unique for each request?

Tags: java, servlets

I have implemented with a servlet with below doGet & doPost methods:

```
        public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
               // code      
            }

        public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
               // code      
            }
```

**My question:** Is the **HttpServletRequest** object in these methods unique for every unique ?

I am using **request.setAttribute("att","value"); method.**  to save some values.

I want to know if I save an attribute in
first request, will be it present in the next request object. (Provided both requests are received at
almost same time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - its a new request every time - any attributes set in one request, will not be there when the next request comes in.

If you want to set attributes that are persistent across requests, you can use:

```
request.getServletContext().setAttribute("att","value");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer :),  Just want to know -- even if there are multiple requests in a single second, this stays same right?  I mean each request will have it's own saved attributes right? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Even if there are multiple concurrent requests arriving at the same moment and handled by different threads.  They will all be unique, and all have their own set of attributes.